# writing a findNumbersInStr function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function in javascript which takes in a string of numbers separated by spaces and returns an array containing only the numbers in the string AS NUMBERS (not strings).

My code is as follows:

```
function findNumbersInStr(strToParse) 

{
    var numbers = new Array();

    if( typeof strToParse !== 'string'){
    return 'undefined';
}
else{
    var arrayNumbers = strToParse.split(" ");

    for (i=0; i < arrayNumbers.length; i++)
    {
        ele = parseInt(arrayNumbers[i]);
        if (typeof ele === "number")
        {
            console.log("this is the " + i + "th loop!");
            var temp = parseInt(arrayNumbers[i]);
            numbers.push(temp);
        }
    } 
}
return numbers; 
}
```

But when I call the function like this:

```
console.log(findNumbersInStr("8 24 what hahaha 3990"));
```

I got the result:  `[8, 24, NaN, NaN, 3990]`
It seems it regards NaN as kind of number.
How could I fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Fix it by removing the `NaN` from the array

Comment: You don't really want to return the string `'undefined'`. Why not an empty array? Or `null` at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `parseInt(nonNumericString)` will evaluate to `NaN` which, when used with `typeof`, evaluates to...surprise...a `number`. Try using a regex instead:

```
var strToParse = "12 2 hello 32 dog 366 cat";
var splitStringArray = strToParse.split(" ");
var storedNumbers = [];
var reg = new RegExp('^\\d+$');

for (i = 0; i < splitStringArray.length; i++) {
    var elem = splitStringArray[i];
    if (reg.test(elem)) {
        storedNumbers.push(elem);
    }
}
alert(storedNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a much simpler function by using a regular expression like so:

```
var findNumbersInStr = function(str){

    if( typeof str !== 'string' ) return;

    return str.match(/(\d+)/g).map(Number)
}

findNumbersInStr("8 24 what hahaha 3990"); // [8, 24, 3990]
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mD22G/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function findNumbersInStr(strToParse) {  
    var matches = strToParse.match(/\d+/g), numbers = [];
    matches.forEach(function(number){
        numbers.push(parseInt(number, 10));
    });
    return numbers;
}
```

Hope this helps and your function may look like above. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/135/)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     ele = parseInt(arrayNumbers[i]);
>     if (typeof ele === "number")
> ```

`typeof NaN == "number"`, so that test won't help much - `parseInt` does not return a non-numeric type if it failed. Instead, use

```
    if (!isNaN(ele))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = [];
var string = "8 24 what hahaha 3990";

var parts = string.split(" ");
for(i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    var number = parseInt(parts[i]);
    if(!isNaN(number)) numbers.push(number);
}

// numbers => [8, 24, 3990]
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES5, it's easy:

```
"8 24 what hahaha 3990"
    .split(/ +/)                               // Split into array
    .map(function(i){return +i;})              // Convert to numbers
    .filter(function(i){return !isNaN(i);})    // Remove NaNs
```

With ES6, it's even better:

```
"8 24 what hahaha 3990"
    .split(/ +/)               // Split into array
    .map(i => +i)              // Convert to numbers
    .filter(i => !isNaN(i))    // Remove NaNs
```

<sub>(Note ES6 browser support is negligible)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version:

```
(string.match(/[0-9]+/g) || []).map(Number)
```

You'll get all numbers, and only numbers.

If you also want to verify that the input is a string you can do this, although it's probably over-complicated for a one-liner:

```
((typeof string == 'string' && string.match(/[0-9]+/g)) || []).map(Number)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are valid numbers with decimal points, and minus signs, and e(1.2345e10):

```
function matchNumbers(str){
    var ns= str.match(/-?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?/g) || []
    return ns.map(Number);
}
var s= "8 24 what hahaha 3990";
matchNumbers(s)
```

/*  returned value: (Array)
8,24,3990
*/